# How to generate AUTOMATIC Numbers in Teradata SQL to strictly increment by 1

Tags: sql, teradata, auto-increment

There is an ETL Audit framework with 4 tables. They are Batch, Job, BatchControl and JobControl tables. Batch and Job are like dimensions tables. The values into these 2 tables are being entered manually using insert statements. BatchControl and JobControl are like facts tables that represent the transactions being done by the records present in Batch and Job tables respectively.

DDL for the batch table is:

| BATCHID | BATCHNAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |

The structure of the BatchControl table looks like this:

| BATCHCONTROLID | BATCHID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |

When ever a batch a new batch is getting started a new record will be inserted into the BatchControl table. Since at any given point in time, only one record is going to be inserted into the BatchControl table.
So when ever a new record is going to be inserted the BatchControlID in the new record is going to be max(BatchControlID) + 1. Thus here we were able to attain a consistent auto increment by 1 with out relying on the auto increment provided by the TD.

The real problem arises with the JobControl table. There could be multiple jobs associated with a batch. All those jobs are stored in the Job table. The structure of the Job table looks like this:

The structure of the Job table looks like this:

| JOBID | JOBNAME | BATCHID | ACTIVEYN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The structure of the JobControl table looks like this:

| JOBCONTROLID | BATCHCONTROLID | JOBID | STARTTIME | ENDTIME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The DDL block for JOBCONTROLID is :

```
JOBCONTROLID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 1 
            MAXVALUE 2147483647 
            NO CYCLE)
```

This is working fine but the auto increment is not consistent due to Teradata AMP's.

For example purposes there is a Batch with BatchID value 1 and there are 10 jobs associated with it in the job table.

All these 10 jobs will be inserted into the JobControl table in one go by using an insert statement like this:

```
insert into ETLAUDIT.JOBCONTROL (JOBCONTROLID,BATCHCONTROLID,JOBID,STARTTIME,ENDTIME,STATUS) select 
1 AS BATCHCONTROLID,
JOBID,
NULL AS STARTTIME,
NULL AS ENDTIME,
NULL AS STATUS
from ETLAUDIT.Job where BatchID = 1;
```

Didn't pass the JOBCONTROLID in the select bloc because it is an auto increment by 1 in the DDL. But now consistency needs to attained in the Auto-increment part for JobControlID too so that the values always increase by 1 exactly (Similar to what is achieved for BatchControlID).

How can the auto-increment by 1 be implemented strictly so that the JobControlID values always auto-increment by 1 exactly? Any suggestions on how this can be achieved are also welcome.

Comment: Auto-increment columns -- and sequences as well -- use cacheing for performance purposes. They are not really sequential as their name implies, but *mostly* sequential. If you really need strict sequentiality, then you'll need to implement it as a **single-threaded** process, controlled by some kind of lock.

Comment: Also, *visible* values such as this are quite unfit for PKs. Use a secondary column to produce values that are visible in the UI or send to an external app. PK values are internal and it's not important if they are sequential or not; the only important aspect is that they need to be *unique*.

Comment: If you want to control the sequence you have to implement it on your own, e.g. using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Job.JobID) + (Select max(JobControlID) from ETLAUDIT.JobControl) AS JobControlID``` . It solved the issue. You can post the same as an answer and I am ready to accept to it. @Dnoeth